# FOSElasticaBundle which version of Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, symfony, foselasticabundle

I've just installed elasticasearch last version. Looks like this bundle doesn't support version 5.0.2? Cause I've got this error

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Wrong parameters for Elastica\Exception\ResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]])
```

Which version of elasticasearch should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current project I run https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-4-2 with "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.1"